# To prove how limit exists using definition given.

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

The definition of a limit of a complex function goes as follows:- Let a function f be defined at all points z in some deleted neighbourhood of z°.  Then the limit of f(z) as z approaches z° is a number w° . That means for each positive number ε , there is a positive number δ such that |f(z)- w°| is less than ε whenever| z-z° | lies between 0 & δ.
Now I am asked to prove

i).  limiting value of ( Re z) as z tends to z° equals (Re z°).

ii). limiting value of conjugate of z equals conjugate of z° as z tends to z°.

using definition given above.

I have difficulty as I don't know how to start.

Comment: Start by noting that $\mathrm{Re}(z)-\mathrm{Re}(z_0) = \mathrm{Re}(z-z_0)$ and $\overline{z}-\overline{z_0}=\overline{z-z_0}$. Now try to show that $|\mathrm{Re}(z-z_0)|$, $|\overline{z-z_0}|$ cannot be very large if $|z-z_0|$ is small.

Comment: Start with $|Re(z)-Re(z^o)|=|Re(z-z^o)|\leq |z-z^o|$ and $|Im(z)-Im(z^o)|=|Im(z-z^o)|\le |z-z^o|.$

Answer (score 0):

i) Note that as $z \to z_0$, $\forall \epsilon > 0,$ take $\delta := \epsilon$ such that $\forall z: 0 < |z-z_0| < \delta, $
$$|\mathrm{Re}(z) - \mathrm{Re}(z_0)| \le \sqrt{(\mathrm{Re}(z) - \mathrm{Re}(z_0))^2 + (\mathrm{Im}(z) - \mathrm{Im}(z_0))^2} = |z-z_0|<\epsilon.$$

$$\text{Hence, } \lim_{z\to z_0} \mathrm{Re}(z) = \mathrm{Re}(z_0).$$

ii) As $z \to z_0$, $\forall \epsilon > 0,$ take $\delta := \epsilon$ such that $\forall z: 0 < |z-z_0| < \delta, $
$$|\overline{z}-\overline{z_0}| = |\overline{z-z_0}| = |z-z_0|<\epsilon.$$

$$\text{Hence, } \lim_{z\to z_0} \overline{z} = \overline{z_0}.$$